# Hyperbolic function of matrix exponential $\exp\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0 & P \\ P & 0\end{smallmatrix}t\right)$

Tags: matrices, exponential-function

I am reading a paper, and I am confused about the following equality:

$$\exp\bigg(\begin{bmatrix}0 & P \\ P & 0\end{bmatrix}t\bigg)=\begin{bmatrix} \cosh(Pt) & \sinh(Pt)\\ \sinh(Pt) & \cosh(Pt)\end{bmatrix}$$

where $P\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

We know that $$\cosh(P) = \frac{1}{2}[\exp(P)+\exp(-P)],\quad \sinh(P) = \frac{1}{2}[\exp(P)-\exp(-P)]$$

and we know if $P$ is a diagonal matrix, then $\exp(P)$ can be obtained by putting exponential function to each element on the diagonal of $P$.

However, today $P$ is general, how to derive the quality?

Comment: Why don't you just calculate the powers of your matrix. Then you will see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&P\\P&0\end{bmatrix}^k=\begin{bmatrix}P^k&0\\0&P^k\end{bmatrix} $$
if $k$ is even, while
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&P\\P&0\end{bmatrix}^k=\begin{bmatrix}0&P^k\\P^k&0\end{bmatrix} $$
is $k$ is odd. Therefore
$$ \exp\Big(t\begin{bmatrix}0&P\\P&0\end{bmatrix}\Big)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^k}{k!}\begin{bmatrix}0&P\\P&0\end{bmatrix}^k$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{2k}}{(2k)!}\begin{bmatrix}P^{2k}&0\\0&P^{2k}\end{bmatrix}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\begin{bmatrix}0&P^{2k+1}\\P^{2k+1}&0\end{bmatrix} $$
$$ =\begin{bmatrix}\cosh(tP)&\sinh(tP)\\\sin(tP)&\cosh(tP)\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Is that a typo in the bottom left of the result matrix (sin instead of sinh)